# Is it good to put experience if the job is for fresher (entry-level)?

Tags: resume, software-industry, india

Is it good to put experience if the job is for fresher (entry-level), I am little confused about this, I am thinking that if they mention that the job is for fresher then they will be looking for fresher so that they can train them on a their required technology and will put us into that.

So if I mention my experience then to whom they prefer,me or to a fresher for selecting?

I am a fresher 2014 graduate but having 9 months of experience in an IT company (Software Development).

Comment: Sorry, for those of us not familiar with the terminology: What do you mean by fresher?

Comment: It might help to add the tag specifying which country this is in...
I'm guessing that "fresher" is specific to a particular dialect of English. By inference, I'm guessing it means "someone who is looking for his or her first real full-time job," possibly adapted from "freshman".

Comment: Yes,In india fresher means who is recently graduated and not having any past industry experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you should include *all* of your relevant experience.**

If your 9 months of Software Development experience is at all relevant for the position you are seeking, then you should include it in your resume.

Your experience is something you have that few other freshers will have. You already know how to work, presumably in a corporate setting. That may make it valuable for your potential employer.

Employers are seldom worried that they can only train someone who has never worked before. If you can learn one technology stack, it's not a stretch to imagine you could learn another. And during your interview, if it should come up, you can easily stress how happy you would be to learn their technology.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should mention your experience. Remember that you are competing with students who have 3-9 months of summer internship experience. And part time jobs. This is a "nice to have" when employers are looking for an entry level job.

Answer (score 2):

Employers see unexplained holes of non-activity (and that's not just not working, that's not working and not doing anything productive to fill the time either) as red flags. And lying over something like this (you weren't in prison or anything) isn't worth it. 
Long-term unemployment is perceived much worse than slight overqualification. I mean, 9 months could just have been an internship. If you're applying to internships they may not hire you because of this, but otherwise I don't see a problem.

So I think it is better to just write it down. 
They may not hire you because you're overqualified and they want to pay the employee a low wage, so they wouldn't want someone with more experience who will fly away from the job he's overqualified for as soon as he can. 
I don't think the fact that you have 9 months of experience would be considered as something that makes you too hard to train (as opposed to a 50 years old programmer who didn't keep his knowledge up-to-date).

Whether they would prefer a fresh graduate over you depends on their reason for looking for a fresh graduate, but I think it's possible.

There's also the issue of why your previous employment lasted only 9 months though, just hope you can get to the point where they ask you that question (unless you were fired). Disregard this if it was an internship.

Comment: Please be less judgemental about 50 year old programmers ageism has no place hear exactly the same as sexism and racism

Comment: @Pepone: "Didn't keep skills up-to-date" is not ageism.

Comment: @BenVoigt it was the implied ageism

Comment: Ageism is a reality, I'm not judgemental, passing on wisdom is a valuable thing and firing older people just because a young and cheaper person can do the job well enough (or at least who makes the decisions believes so) is a throwing it in the trash.
I hear about it happening all the time though.